# Reading and extracting files from a directory using SAS

Tags: sas

I have a directory ***/run/return/files/archives/prep/share/*** that contains both .txt and .csv files.
For example **IA_PROD.txt** and **retour_PROD.csv**
I want to read both types of files and extract only their names (IA_PROD and retour_PROD) to store in an excel file named FILE_NAMES.xlsx. I have the code below that extracts .txt and .csv files though two separate data sets (file_list1 and file_list2) and I finally concatenate the two data sets to export in an excel sheet. I wanted to be able to optimise my code to make it one single data step where I read both csv, txt and extract both of them together.

Thanks for your generous help

```
%let REP_BLOCTEL_ALLER = /run/return/files/archives/prep/share/;
filename result pipe "ls &rep_bloctel_aller./*txt";
filename result2 pipe "ls &rep_bloctel_aller./*csv";

data file_list1;
     infile result lrecl=200 truncover;
     input rep $120.;
     file_name = tranwrd(substr(rep, length("&rep_bloctel_aller./")+1),'.txt','');
     call symput(compress('txt_'!!put(_n_,2.)),file_name);
     call symput('n_obs',put(_n_,2.));
run;


data file_list2;
     infile result2 lrecl=200 truncover;
     input rep $120.;
     file_name = tranwrd(substr(rep, length("&rep_bloctel_aller./")+1),'.csv','');
     call symput(compress('csv_'!!put(_n_,2.)),file_name);
     call symput('n_obs',put(_n_,2.));
run;


DATA file_list;
     SET file_list1 file_list2;
RUN;

   

proc export data = file_list
     (keep = file_name)
     outfile="&rep_bloctel_aller./FILE_NAME_BLOCTEL.xlsx"
     dbms=xlsx
     replace;
     sheet= "FILE_NAME_BLOCTEL";
run;
```

Comment: Do you really need to generate all of those macro variables along the way?  Do you need to have a SAS dataset? Or is it ok to just write the list directly to the XLSX file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it answers your question, but I think this answers your problem :)

What I propose it to filter your input files with `ls` :

```
%let REP_BLOCTEL_ALLER = /run/return/files/archives/prep/share/;

filename result pipe "ls &file_path. | egrep -i '\.csv$|\.txt$'";

data file_list;
     infile result lrecl=200 truncover;
     input filename $120.;
run;
```

I don't think we can make it shorter!

Some explanations:

- `ls` lists your directory
- the pipe `|` forwards the result of `ls` to the `egrep` command
- `egrpe` is used to search for text value in the result sent by `ls`

  - the `-i` option indicates to `egrep` that text lookup must be case insensitive (will detect TXT, txt, TxT files and so on)
  - The '.csv$|.txt$' indicates to search for either '.csv' or '.txt' at the end of a line (`$`), which corresponds to the file the extension

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to just generate the list into an XLSX file then you just need:

```
libname out xlsx "&rep_bloctel_aller./FILE_NAME_BLOCTEL.xlsx";
data out.FILE_NAME_BLOCTEL;
  infile "cd &rep_bloctel_aller.; ls *.txt *.csv" pipe truncover;
  input file_name $256.;
run;
```